# element not allowed error itextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

iam trying to convert html to pdf using itextsharp. But all the time get the error 'element not allowed' Html formatted using HtmlAgilityPack.
.....................................................................................................................................................................................................
 here is my code

```
 hDocument.LoadHtml(html);
            var closedTags = hDocument.DocumentNode.WriteTo();
            var _cssSource = Server.MapPath("~/css/style.css");
            var css = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_cssSource);
            var memoryStram = new MemoryStream();
            var memmoryStram = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memmoryStram);
            document.Open();
            using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css)))
            {
                using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(closedTags)))
                {
                    // XMLWorker _worker = new XMLWorker(
                    StringReader htmls = new StringReader(html);
                    var p = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
                    p.ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream);
                }
            }
            document.Close();
```

Error :

```
         at iTextSharp.text.pdf.ColumnText.AddElement(IElement element)
      at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell.AddElement(IElement element)
     at iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.table.TableData.End(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, IList`1 currentContent)
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.EndElement(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, IList`1 currentContent)
   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.Close(IWorkerContext context, Tag t, ProcessObject po)
 at iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorker.EndElement(String tag, String ns)
 at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.EndElement()
 at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.Process(Char character)
 at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.ParseWithReader(TextReader reader)
  at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.Parse(TextReader reader)
 at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.Parse(Stream inp)
  at iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.ParseXHtml(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, Stream inp, Stream inCssFile, Encoding charset, IFontProvider fontProvider, String resourcesRootPath)
  at iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.ParseXHtml(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, Stream inp, Stream inCssFile, Encoding charset, IFontProvider fontProvider)
  at iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.ParseXHtml(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, Stream inp, Stream inCssFile)
  at IBATechnologies.IBA.SyncApp.Interface.Controllers.UtilitiesController.pdfBytes(String html) in E:\IBASyncApp\IBA.SyncApp.Interface\IBATechnologies.IBA.SyncApp.Interface\Controllers\UtilitiesController.cs:line 54
```

closedTags

```
     <!-- ngInclude: _rpt.tmpUrl --><div class="col-all-12 PDF-report-holder   ng-  scope" ng-include="_rpt.tmpUrl"><table id="myTable" class="table-responsive ng-scope">
     <tbody><tr class="header">
   <th colspan="5">
   <h2 class="col-all-12"> Branch</h2>
   <p class="col-all-12 ng-binding">WMS Stock Status - Item Summary</p>
  </th>

 <th class="-Pdf-logo">
       <a href="http://technologies.com/" class="col-all-12"><img       src="/image/default/logo.png" /></a>
     </th>
     </tr>
     <tr class="-Pdf-head">
  <td>SKU</td>
   <td>Base Unit</td>
   <td>Base Qty</td>
  <td>Pltpos(s)</td>
   <td>CBM</td>
   <td>Weight TON</td>

    </tr>
     </tbody><!-- ngRepeat: cust in _rpt.data --><tbody ng-repeat="cust in _rpt.data"    class="ng-scope">
<tr>
<td colspan="6"><strong><p class="ng-binding">Test Customer</p></strong></td>

 </tr>
  <!-- ngRepeat: row in cust.itemGroup --><tr ng-repeat="row in    cust.itemGroup"     ng-repeat-finished="rpt_ng_repeat" class="ng-scope">
     <td><p class="ng-binding">100 Test Item</p></td>
      <td><p class="ng-binding">PLT</p></td>
      <td><p class="ng-binding">68</p></td>
        <td><p class="ng-binding">68</p></td>
       <td><p class="ng-binding">68</p></td>
       <td><p class="ng-binding">0.068</p></td>
       </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: row in cust.itemGroup -->
       <tr class="-Pdf-head">
       <td colspan="3"><p>Total</p></td>
     <td><p class="ng-binding">68</p></td>
   <td><p class="ng-binding">68</p></td>
   <td><p class="ng-binding">0.068</p></td>
   </tr>
       </tbody><!-- end ngRepeat: cust in _rpt.data -->
      </table>
    </div>
```

api Call

```
  public ActionResult DownloadPdf(string file_name,string html)
    {

        var _memStream = pdfBytes(html);
        var _pdfDoc = new PdfContent
        {
            MemoryStream = _memStream,
            FileName = file_name
        };
        return _pdfDoc;
    }
```

Response

```
public class PdfContent : ActionResult
{
    public MemoryStream MemoryStream { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName + ".pdf");
        response.OutputStream.Write(MemoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, MemoryStream.GetBuffer().Length);
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.PDF-report{position:fixed; top:0; right:-100%; background:#fff; width:75%; height:100%; z-index:100; padding:10px; border-left:1px solid #ccc} .PDF - report - active{ right: 0}
                        .PDF - report table{background:#fff; min-width:100%}.PDF - report table td{ min - width:100px;}.IBA - Pdf - logo img{ float:right}.IBA - Pdf - head{ border - top:5px solid #000; font-weight:bold }.PDF - report - holder{ height: 100 %; overflow: scroll} .col-all-12{width:100%;}
                        .col-all-12, .all-col{height:auto; padding:0; margin:0; float:left}
```

Comment: Your error stack trace does not mention any iText classes. Thus, either the error is completely unrelated to your iText usage or you pasted a wrong or incomplete stack trace.

Comment: @mkl , updated stack trace. please help

Comment: Ok, it looks like the issue occurs way down in some table. Please share the contents of `closedTags` to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: @mkl qstn updated

Comment: Have you tried just simple html does it worked ?

Comment: Yes, simple html works fine without any errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The cause

Apparently iText `XMLWorker` does not accept heading elements (`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, or `h6`) inside table header elements (`th`): If you remove the `h2` element here

```
<th colspan="5">
  <h2 class="col-all-12"> Branch</h2>
  <p class="col-all-12 ng-binding">WMS Stock Status - Item Summary</p>
</th>
```

or make it e.g. a paragraph element (`p`), there is no exception anymore.

You can verify this using a cut down example:

```
<table><tr><td><h1>Test</h1></td></tr></table>
```

and

```
<table><tr><th><p>Test</p></th></tr></table>
```

both are processed by `XMLWorker` but

```
<table><tr><th><h1>Test</h1></th></tr></table>
```

is rejected with the same exception as your HTML.

## The specification

According to the HTML5 specification heading elements inside table headers *actually are not allowed:*

> #### 4.9.10 The `th` element
>
> [...]
>
> Content model:
>
> Flow content, but with no header, footer, sectioning content, or **heading content** descendants.

*([HTML5 section 4.9 Tabular Data](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-th-element))*

where **heading content** is defined as

> #### 3.2.4.1.4 Heading content
>
> **Heading content** defines the header of a section (whether explicitly marked up using sectioning content elements, or implied by the heading content itself).
>
> => h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6

*([HTML5 section 3 Semantics, structure, and APIs of HTML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#heading-content-0))*

## The bottom line

So your HTML input is not valid HTML and, therefore, iText (or any HTML processor) may fail processing it.

---

## The test code

As a reference, derived from your code this is the code I used for testing:

```
public void CreatePdfAjithOriginal()
{
    String html = "<!-- ngInclude: _rpt.tmpUrl -->"
        + "<div class=\"col-all-12 PDF-report-holder ng-scope\" ng-include=\"_rpt.tmpUrl\">"
          + "<table id=\"myTable\" class=\"table-responsive ng-scope\">"
            + "<tbody>"
              + "<tr class=\"header\">"
                + "<th colspan=\"5\">"
//                  + "<h2 class=\"col-all-12\"> Branch</h2>"
                  + "<p class=\"col-all-12 ng-binding\">WMS Stock Status - Item Summary</p>"
                + "</th>"
                + "<th class=\"-Pdf-logo\">"
                  + "<a href=\"http://technologies.com/\" class=\"col-all-12\"><img src=\"/image/default/logo.png\" /></a>"
                + "</th>"
              + "</tr>"
              + "<tr class=\"-Pdf-head\">"
                + "<td>SKU</td>"
                + "<td>Base Unit</td>"
                + "<td>Pltpos(s)</td>"
                + "<td>CBM</td>"
                + "<td>Weight TON</td>"
              + "</tr>"
            + "</tbody>"
            + "<!-- ngRepeat: cust in _rpt.data -->"
            + "<tbody ng-repeat=\"cust in _rpt.data\" class=\"ng-scope\">"
              + "<tr>"
                + "<td colspan=\"6\"><strong><p class=\"ng-binding\">Test Customer</p></strong></td>"
              + "</tr>"
              + "<!-- ngRepeat: row in cust.itemGroup -->"
              + "<tr ng-repeat=\"row in cust.itemGroup\" ng-repeat-finished=\"rpt_ng_repeat\" class=\"ng-scope\">"
                + "<td><p class=\"ng-binding\">100 Test Item</p></td>"
                + "<td><p class=\"ng-binding\">PLT</p></td>"
                + "<td><p class=\"ng-binding\">68</p></td>"
                + "<td><p class=\"ng-binding\">68</p></td>"
                + "<td><p class=\"ng-binding\">68</p></td>"
                + "<td><p class=\"ng-binding\">0.068</p></td>"
              + "</tr>"
              + "<!-- end ngRepeat: row in cust.itemGroup -->"
              + "<tr class=\"-Pdf-head\">"
                + "<td colspan=\"3\"><p>Total</p></td>"
                + "<td><p class=\"ng-binding\">68</p></td>"
                + "<td><p class=\"ng-binding\">68</p></td>"
                + "<td><p class=\"ng-binding\">0.068</p></td>"
              + "</tr>"
            + "</tbody>"
            + "<!-- end ngRepeat: cust in _rpt.data -->"
          + "</table>"
        + "</div>";
    // A minimal example provoking the exception:
//    String html = "<table><tr><th><h1>Test</h1></th></tr></table>";
    String css = ".PDF-report{position:fixed; top:0; right:-100%; background:#fff; width:75%; height:100%; z-index:100; padding:10px; border-left:1px solid #ccc}"
        + " .PDF-report-active{ right: 0}"
        + " .PDF-report table{background:#fff; min-width:100%}"
        + " .PDF-report table td{ min-width:100px;}"
        + " .IBA-Pdf-logo img{ float:right}"
        + " .IBA-Pdf-head{ border-top:5px solid #000; font-weight:bold }"
        + " .PDF-report-holder{ height: 100 %; overflow: scroll}"
        + " .col-all-12{width:100%;}"
        + " .col-all-12, .all-col{height:auto; padding:0; margin:0; float:left}";

    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Temp\test-results\xmlworker\");
    var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\test-results\xmlworker\AjithOriginal.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    document.Open();
    using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css)))
    {
        using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
        {
            var p = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            p.ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream);
        }
    }
    document.Close();
}
```

Both in the html and the css extra spaces have been removed from your sources as I assumed them to be artifacts introduced when copying to stack overflow. If this assumption is wrong, the original HTML and CSS should really be sanitized before continuing.

Furthermore, unused code was removed, e.g. the `var memoryStram` and the `StringReader htmls`. The original code should likewise be cleaned.

Anyways, the result of the above is

[image: Screenshot]

You on the other hand say

> The generated pdf file is blank.

and considering your latest code additions I assume you mean that it is displayed blank in some browser. Thus, it either is lost somewhere along the way  to the `HttpContext.Response` or your browser does not like the way it is sent to it.

To verify that the PDF properly gets to the `HttpContext.Response`, you should check that all along the way the `MemoryStream` instances in question do carry the PDF, e.g. by storing the respective `MemoryStream`'s `ToArray()` value to the file system.

A possible issue: you don't show how your method `pdfBytes` actually returns the `MemoryStream`; maybe you use the empty `memoryStram` instead of the `memmoryStram` into which the PDF has been generated...

As soon as you are sure the PDF indeed gets to the `HttpContext.Response` with being damaged, test again with the browser. If that still does not work, try different browsers (some browsers require that you set the content length HTTP return header) and also try to save to PDF from the browser instead of trying to view it. You might even have to inspect the data exchanged over the network connection, e.g. using wireshark. Here are many possible tripwires to evade...

Comment: thank you so much. You are genius. I would like to contact directly when i facing issues. If you dnt mind can you share your linkd in id plz...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on linkedIn. But I'm present here.

Comment: its ok... Thank you

Comment: The generated pdf file is blank. help me plz

Comment: It is not for my copy of your code. Thus, there is something special in your actual code or data which you haven't mentioned here.

Comment: You have not provided the css yet. Probably in them there is some issue, too.

Comment: @Ajith Even with your css (having cleaned up invalid spaces) I get a non-empty PDF. Thus, I added my test code to the answer and some hints how to debug your application. Following those hints you should be able to find out at which stage the PDF becomes empty. As soon as you know that, it may make sense to continue the analysis.